# Count the number of child components by tag name in angular2 unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, jasmine

I have a parent component which will dynamically insert the child components based on the length of array. I want to test the number of components created, by using its tag name.

```
<div *ngFor = "let item of phoneList; let i = index">
    <phone-item [item]="item"> </phone-item>
</div>
```

I want to verify the number of `<phone-item></phone-item>` created within the html template in angular2 unit testing.

I have very little knowledge on debugElement and nativeElement. This is what I have tried to do.

```
let el = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('phone-item'));
```

But I want the count of child components created.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [DebugElement#queryAll](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DebugElement-class.html#!#queryAll-anchor) which returns an array. [`query`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/DebugElement-class.html#!#query-anchor) only returns the first matching